# HTML - How to have fixed menus arround a dynamic content

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a webpage with a fixed header and footer (both 50px high) and between them the content which gets the rest of the screen. No Scrollbar should appear. I got this working. But now I want to have for the content a menubar on the left and right, also both fixed width with 50px and again the content gets the space between it with no scrollbar. The only not so nice thing I had to do was to now only have three divs in one row for the content, instead I had to make two divs and split the second one again to two divs. If there would be a solution only using three divs, that would be great. I got it working using the following code:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <header>
      HEADER
    </header>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="left-menu-bar"></div>
      <div id="main-content">
        <div id="main-content-left"></div>
        <div id="main-content-right"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here the css code:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  top: 50px; 
  bottom: 50px; 
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d2d6de;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-menu-bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  float:left;
}

#main-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main-content-left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 455px);
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-content-right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the problem. If in my dynamic content div 'main-content-left' something is written, the 'main-content-left' div shrinks. I tried to insert the following code into 'main-content-left':

```
<div id="content-head">
  Box-Head
</div>        
<div id="content-box">
   Box-Content
</div>
```

**EDIT: follow-up question:**

IS it possible to get a box inside '' which has the full height of the 'main-content-right 'div' but with a margin of 5px around it? If I am creating a div with height 100% the bottom is always behind the footer.

Comment: `top`, `left`, `rght`, `bottom` are functionless without position absolute or relative.

Comment: Removed them, but it did not change anything

Comment: Right, just like ocanal said. Of course they won't change anything if you remove them when you need to have "absolute" or "relative" for them to do anything in the first place.

Comment: Added a follow-up question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `vertical-align` with the `diplay:inline-block` to handle it

```
#main-content-left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 455px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#main-content-right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/75uhgh7e/